# Is it possible to set the same Y axis limit for all plots combined with grid.arrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have eight plots, which I need to combine using `grid.arrange`:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7,p8, nrow=2, ncol=4,
layout_matrix = cbind(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8))) + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))
```

But these eight plots have different Y-axis ranges... Is it possible to apply the same Y-axis limit in `grid.arrange`?

Comment: I'd recommend setting a `scale_y_*` for each individual plot, or working with facets. I don't think it is possible within `grid.arrange`.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if `ggpubr::ggarrange` is helpful for this.

```
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7,p8, nrow=2, ncol=4, align = c("h"))
```

This will align the `y` axis, or replace `align = c("h")` with `align = c("hv")` to align both `x` and `y`.

Comment: ggarrange did not help. I am using a loop to create the plots p1, p2,...from separate data frames (before adding them into one figure with grid.arrange). So it seems that solution is this: I have to run the code once, look which individual plot has maximum Y-axis range, then set ymax accordingly, then run the code again.